# Sum of dict elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of names and ages. Some of the names are identical. I want to sum the age of the names that are identical.

My fake data looks like this:

```
pete: 33
ann: 7
ruth: 3
ann: 5
austin: 90
```

In the examples there are two anns. So I want to sum the ages of the two anns.
Currently I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'pete':33,'ann':7,'ruth':3,'ann':5,'austin':90}
```

My result should look like this

```
dict = {'pete':33,'ann':12,'ruth':3,'austin':90}

pete: 33
ann: 12
ruth: 3
austin: 90
```

I think to put the data in a dictionary like this isn't the best solution. What is a good other solution to store the data and process them into the output?

Comment: `{'pete':33,'ann':7,'ruth':3,'ann':5,'austin':90}` -- dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. If you print this dict you'll see that only one of the `ann` entries survived.

Comment: Yes, I figured that. That's why I am looking for a different way to store/process the data.

Comment: @user1738154 Well, what is your data initially? It, can't be a dict as the data won't be there. Is it in a file?

Comment: I just created it randomly. Imagine there are two people called `ann`

Comment: The point is that any answer is going to depend on what the data source is.  A file you're reading?  A database?  Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fake data *can not* look like that. it's impossible to have two entries with the same key in a dictionary, perhaps you meant to use a different data structure? (not a dictionary). But if your data looked like this:

```
input = [('pete', 33), ('ann',7), ('ruth',3), ('ann',5), ('austin',90)]
```

*Then* a `defaultdict` would be a good idea:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in input:
    d[k] += v

d
=> defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'pete': 33, 'ann': 12, 'ruth': 3, 'austin': 90})
```

Or using a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter()

for k, v in input:
    d.update({k:v})

d
=> Counter({'austin': 90, 'pete': 33, 'ann': 12, 'ruth': 3})
```

And yet another solution, without importing extra libraries:

```
d = {}
for k, v in input:
    if k in d:
        d[k] += v
    else:
        d[k] = v

d
=> {'pete': 33, 'ann': 12, 'ruth': 3, 'austin': 90}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I know I didn't ask that in the questions. But is there also a way to this without importing anything? The background is because I like to do this in ArcGIS field calculator.

Comment: Sure, with a bit more of work you can do the same that is done in the libraries. See my updated answer

Comment: For the last solution, where you're trying to avoid even the standard library, I prefer `d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v` over the if.  Or `d.setdefault(k, [])` when I'm building a dict of lists or the like.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [('pete', 33), ('ann', 7), ('ruth', 3), ('ann', 5), ('austin', 90)]
```

Since dicts can't contain duplicate keys, you could start out with a list of tuples instead.

```
from collections import defaultdict
combined = defaultdict(int)

for name, age in data:
    combined[name] += age
```

Then build the `dict` using `defaultdict`. The trick is that `defaultdict(int)` creates a dict whose entries default to 0 so you don't have to deal with non-existent keys.

Comment: Python 2.7 introduces `collections.Counter`, which can be more convenient, though I still usually default to `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using dictionary, you need to use a list of tuples

```
pairs = [ ('pete', 33), ('ann', 7), ('ruth', 3), ('ann', 5), ('austin', 90) ]
```

Then you can calculate the sum using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
answer = defaultdict(int)
for name, number in pairs:
    answer[name] += number

print(answer)
```

The defaultdict works by calling the given function (int) to give the default value for any keys that do not exist (int() returns conveniently 0); then for each iteration the number is added to that.